# QThread event loop and infinite work loop

Tags: multithreading, qt

I need to make infinite loop of work in a thread.
In [this article](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Threads_Events_QObjects) the author writes that

```
 >you should never ever block the event loop
```

because it will block the signal-slot concept. How can I use event loop plus infinite loop in `QThread`?

Comment: "It will block the signal-slot concept" doesn't really parse. Anyhow, I wrote why it's a bad idea just below, and it has little to do with threading: "With the event delivery stuck, widgets won’t update themselves, no further interaction with widgets is possible, timers won’t fire and networking communications will slow down and stop. Moreover, many window managers will detect that your application is not handling events any more and tell the user that your application isn’t responding". In your case, it just means that your thread won't dispatch events for the objects living in that thread.

Answer (score 5):

QThread is the thread "controller". Its event loop doesn't block just because your QObject executes an infinite loop. Unless of course you're implementing that infinite loop in a QThread subclass.

In your case, you don't have to do that. Instead, just implement your infinite loop in a QObject subclass and then move that QObject to a thread with [QObject::moveToThread()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/qobject.html#moveToThread). That way your infinite loop doesn't block the QThread's event loop.

And, as always: [the canonical article on how to really use QThread](http://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/).

Comment: How to pause/resume thread properly, without blocking event loop?

Answer (score 3):

A loop always can be replaced with a function that is called multiple times (although it's not always convenient). Create a slot and connect a `QTimer` to it. Let the function do the iteration of work.

```
timer = new QTimer();
connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(iteration()));
timer->start(50); 

void MyClass::iteration() {
  if (!timer->isActive()) { return; }
  //do something
}
```

If you want to stop the loop, call `timer->stop()`.

Answer (score 1):

A call to [QCoreApplication::processEvents](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents) should work, but maybe a better solution is to use a [QThreadPool](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qthreadpool.html#details) instead of forcing a thread to keep running.